# Migrating from .net 3.5 to 4.5, Error with System.Xml.Linq

Tags: c#

For few days I'm trying to upgrade my .net 3.5 application to .net 4.5.
I've stuck with error:

The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Xml' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
<add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts" />
<add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" />
<add namespace="System.Xml.Linq" /> <--- RED highligted
</namespaces>
```

Any idea's how to resolve it?
I use XDocument class from System.Xml, so I think that this dependency is mandatory in my project.

I've two dll's

```
System.Xml.Linq Runtime Version v4.0.30319 Version 4.0.0.0
System.Xml Runtime Version v4.0.30319 Version 4.0.0.0
```

And while I'm adding:
`<add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>` to web.config, problem with Linq does not disappear, then it is:

The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
<add namespace="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
<add namespace="System.Configuration" />
<add namespace="System.Linq" />  <--- RED highligted
<add namespace="System.Text" />
<add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
```

Comment: How about `System.Xml.Linq.dll`

Comment: Did you check the project references?

Comment: I've just updated my post.

Comment: Are you sure? I've just created new mvc projcet 4.5.2, and for ex. system.xml is 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to System.Core.dll

Comment: I can't... A reference to 'System.Core' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.